# how to remove write protection of a file via cmd or VBA?

Tags: vba, cmd

i'm coding a macro for word and excel. The output are generated files that should be saved.
Since those files already exist and are write protected, I somehow have to remove the protection. I found a unprotect function in excel but it doesn't really work.
I also didn't find any command for unprotecting via cmd o0

I thought about deleting the files before saving the new ones.
But I'd like to find a solution for unprotecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try attrib command in cmd to change file attributes
`attrib *.xls -r` will help you to remove readonly attribute.

Comment: +1 though showing how to call this it from VBA would have been helpful, too

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to remove the read-only attribute from VBA using the FileSystemObject:

```
Sub RemoveReadOnly(filePath As String)
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim f As Scripting.File
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set f = FSO.GetFile(filePath)

    If fil.Attributes And ReadOnly Then 'It's read-only. Remove that attribute.
        fil.Attributes = fil.Attributes - ReadOnly
    End If
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
RemoveReadOnly "C:\mydir\myReadOnlyFile.dat"
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tx15443%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Note: The above requires setting a reference as follows: Tools > References... > set checkmark next to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

If you don't want to set a reference, then use late binding instead:

```
Sub RemoveReadOnly(filePath As String)
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim fil As Object    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fil = FSO.GetFile(filePath)

    If fil.Attributes And 1 Then '1 = ReadOnly
        fil.Attributes = fil.Attributes - 1
    End If
End Sub
```